# batchfile - Wildcard in replace in for loop

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

I'm trying to get two parts of strings in a file. For this, I need to get the part before and after `-`(space - space). I tried using this code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (downloads.txt) do (
set str=%%A
echo !str!
set "string1=!str: - *=!"
set "string2=!str:* - =!"
echo "!string1!+!string2!"
)
pause
```

The complete output should be

> someURL.com+some file.txt

However, the output actually is:

> "someURL.com - some file.txt+some file.txt"

So there obviously is something wrong in the replace code of my first string. I think it has something to do with the wildcard, as that is the only part which is different.

The contents of downloads.txt look like this:

> someURL.com - some file.txt

**EDIT:**

Using aschipfl's code I fixed it with this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (downloads.txt) do (
set str=%%A
set "strR=!str:* - =!"
for /F "delims=*" %%f in ("!strR!") do set "strL=!str: - %%f=!"
set "strL=!strL: - =!"
echo "!strL!+!strR!"
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the wildcard can only be used as the start of the string to search.

A simple, non bulletproof solution (ex. `=!*&` characters in the string can be a problem), you can, once you have the right part of the string, remove it to get the left part

```dos
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
    for /F "delims=" %%A in (downloads.txt) do (
        rem Get the full string
        set "str=%%A"
        echo !str!

        rem Get the right part of the string
        set "string2=!str:* - =!"

        rem Get the left part of the string just removing the right part
        for /f "delims=" %%B in ("!string2!") do set "string1=!str: - %%B=!"

        echo "[!string1!] [!string2!]"
        echo(

    )
    pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the `-` part occurs once only, and the whole string does not start with `*`, you can do the following:

```
:SUB
set "strR=!str:* - =!"
set "strL=!str: - %strR%=!"
set "strL=!strL: - =!"
```

To use this in a loop, you should place this in a subroutine and call it by `call :SUB`, since there is also immediate `%` variable expansion used.

The string must not contain `=`, `%`, `!`, `^`, otherwise this approach fails.

Comment: This worked amazing, thank you. By modifying the second line so it uses a for loop (%% variables) it works inside my own for loop, see my updated question